# Python 3.9.5 has attribute error in datetime.datetime.now(). how to solve it?

Tags: python, version

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\whitedark\Python\Xample\datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "E:\whitedark\Python\Xample\datetime.py", line 3, in <module>
    todate = datetime.datetime.now()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now' (most like
ly due to a circular import)
```

My code is simple. Just ...

```
import datetime
todate = datetime.datetime.now()
print(todate)
```

That is all. In the example they show, it works. I use Thonny. The code can run perfectly inside Thonny which use python 3.7.9. I don't use F5 to run code. The shell blocks half of my code. I can't see all. So, I use cmd which uses python 3.9.5. Should I uninstall python 3.9.5 and install 3.7.9? or is there another way? I think the higher version is better. Not? or did they remove 'now' attribute in 3.9.5? if so, is there any better site to learn python?

Comment: Did you name your own file `datetime.py`? That seems to be the origin of the circular import

Comment: You should edit your question with the new problem then, that would be easier for people to help

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad. I saw my error. By the way, thanks you for you answer. If you know  a way to install python 3.9.5 into Thonny. Please tell me. I think higher version might be great.